# At what argument $x$ is the tangent to the graph $y=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\ln x$ horizontal?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> At what argument $x$ is the tangent to the graph $y=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\ln x$ horizontal?

Well this is a question which I found in a website.
I found the Derivative to be $(x^2+1)/x$.
As far as I know that should be zero but I can't go any further from there.

Comment: Your derivative has a sign error:
$$y=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\ln x \implies y'=x-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x^2-1}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is actually $\frac{x^2-1}{x}$, so setting that equal to $0$ gets you the roots $x = \pm1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'=x-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x^2-1}{x}$$
Then $y'=0$ for $x=1$ since $y$ is defined for $x >0$, the curve has horizontal tangent at $x=1$, $y=\frac{1}{2}$.